# Robot to manipulate poultry

Tags: robotic-arm

I am a software engineer and also a poultry farmer.

I periodically have to manipulate my poultry in such a way as to grab their head and hold them for a brief period, approximately 10 - 30 seconds.  This is an extremely labor-intensive process and it occurred to me that I might be able to use robotics to do the same task.  I am a software engineer so I know very little about robotics and am hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.  Can someone please refer me to companies and/or robotic systems that might be able to help me with this task?

I currently load the poultry into cages specifically designed for this process.  I am thinking that these cages could still be used as they keep the birds from running and make it much easier to capture their heads.

I recently read about a Raspberry PI that had a port of Deep Belief image recognition SDK and thought this might be a promising start.

Comment: Is this a de-beaking robot?

Comment: Is there a video of the process you are trying to automate?  The mechanism you need will depend a lot on the range of motion that needs to be supported, both for the grab and for the positioning.

Comment: Yes there are videos of the process and it is not de-beaking.  I am reticent to mention what the process is or provide videos due to the fact that some consider it inhumane.  However, I always endeavor to treat my birds as humanely as possible.  This is not a, "I need to figure this out now", but more a "Is this possible with current known technology".  This all may seem a little vague and my apologies if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Georgia Tech Research Institute (GTRI) does research on automated poultry processing (http://foodtech.gatech.edu/robotics-automation.html).  You might start there.